# Adding static attributes to JAX-B generated elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Suppose I have a JAXB element like this:

```
@XmlElement
private double value;
```

this will generate XML like this:

```
<value>3.14159</value>
```

Now, how do I modify my declaration (or customize JAXB marshalling) to generate XML like this instead:

```
<value type="double">3.14159</value>
```

The `type` attribute will always have the same value, i.e. "double".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to a define a class that encapsulates the combination of the double and the string, and then annotate a static fixed value:

```
public class MyDouble {
    @XmlValue
    private double value;

    @XmlAttribute(name="type")
    private final static String TYPE = "double";

}
```

So then your code becomes:

```
@XmlElement
private MyDouble value;
```

Comment: Perfect. I always forget about @XmlValue. Thanks!